# Obtaining Angular Momentum of a Rigid Rod from Linear Momentum

Tags: angular-momentum, momentum, moment-of-inertia

Next problem shows a rigid rod with mass 'm' and length 'L', rotation only occurs on the Z axis in the $\hat{k}$ direction. Angular momentum can be easily calculated by using equation:

$H_{G/O} = I_{zz}\dot{\theta}$

Result is shown on figure in RED color

$H_{G/O} = \frac{mL^{2}}{12}\dot{\theta}\hat{k}$

But I am looking to obtain the same result by using linear momentum, like on BLUE equation. I am not sure if it is correct to assume that the Linear momentum $P_{G/O}$ of a rigid body is of the form:

$P_{G/O}=\int \rho V_{G/O} dv$

Where $\rho$ is the density and the integral is calculated with respect to the volume, it is highlighted on yellow at the figure.

Question: How $P_{G/O}$ is obtained and what is its value so $H_{G/O}$ in blue is equal to $H_{G/O}$ in red???

[image]
Better drawn problem for more reference, D = L. Pivot 'P' is the origin point 'O' on previous figure.

[image]

Comment: Images with formulas in them aren't recommended here because they're not searchable.

Comment: I don't understand what $I_{zz}$ should mean, or even the subscript $G/O$. Could you explain that.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true for an extended body that $\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{p}$.

The linear Momentum is
$$
\mathbf{p}(t) = \int_\mathbb{Vol}\rho(\mathbf{r},t)\, \dot{\mathbf{r}}(\mathbf{r},t)\ dv
$$
where $\dot{\mathbf{r}}(\mathbf{r},t)$ is the velocitiy of the point $\mathbf{r}$ at time $t$, and $\rho$ is the densty. In this case we have $\dot{\mathbf{r}} = r\,\dot{\theta} \hat{\theta}$ and $\rho = m/L$
$$
\mathbf{p} = \int_0^L \frac{m}{L}\,r\, \dot{\theta} \hat{\theta}\ dr
= \frac{m}{L}\, \dot{\theta} (\frac{L^2}{2})\, \hat{\theta}
=\frac{mL}{2}\, \dot{\theta} \hat{\theta}\
$$
Of course the velocity is wrt the fixed point $\mathcal{O}$. The angular momentum is
$$
\mathbf{L}(t) = \int_\mathbb{Vol}\rho(\mathbf{r},t)\,\mathbf{r}\times \dot{\mathbf{r}}(\mathbf{r},t)\ dv = \int_\mathbb{Vol}\mathbf{r}\times \overline{\mathbf{p}}(t)\ dv
$$
where $\overline{\mathbf{p}}(t)$ is the momentum density. In our case we have
$$
\mathbf{L} = \int_0^L \frac{m}{L}\,(r\, \hat{r}) \times (r\, \dot{\theta} \hat{\theta})\ dr
= \int_0^L \frac{m}{L}\,r^2\, \dot{\theta} \hat{k}\ dr
=\frac{mL^2}{3}\, \dot{\theta} \hat{k}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, linear momentum is *always* total mass times the velocity of the center of mass. This is derived by the volume integral of a rotating body (as [seen here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/616475/268448) but with sums instead of integrals).

But to develop the equations of motion you need both linear momentum and angular momentum about the center of mass **G**.

You cannot use linear momentum to derive angular momentum because the mass distribution around the center of mass is lost in the $\int \rho\, \boldsymbol{v}\, {\rm d}V$ integral.

Again see the linked post above which explains this process in detail.

> ### Translational Momentum
>
> Add up the momentum of each particle
> $$ \require{cancel} \begin{aligned} \vec{p} & = \sum_i m_i \vec{v}_i = \sum_i m_i ( \vec{v}_C + \vec{\omega}\times \vec{d}_i ) \\ 
>  & =  \left( \sum_i m_i \right)  \vec{v}_C + \vec{\omega}\times \cancel{ \left( \sum_i m_i \vec{d}_i \right)} = m \, \vec{v}_C \end{aligned} \tag{3} $$
> where $m = \sum_i m_i$
>
> #### Rotational Momentum
>
> Add up all the angular momentum about the center of mass
> $$  \begin{aligned}
>  \vec{L}_C & = \sum_i \vec{d}_i \times (m_i \vec{v}_i) = \sum_i  \vec{d}_i \times m_i ( \vec{v}_C + \vec{\omega}\times \vec{d}_i ) \\
>  & = \cancel{\left(\sum_i m_i \vec{d}_i\right)} \times \vec{v}_C + \sum_i m_i \vec{d}_i \times ( \vec{\omega} \times \vec{d}_i ) \\
>  & = \mathbf{I}_C\, \vec{\omega}
> \end{aligned} \tag{4} $$